# How to reset all Models on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My requirement: **Have to reset my select boxes on button click**

Example :-

I have 3 select boxes. When I click on the select box some different data will come and after that the result will get published. I added a Remove button which resets only its parent select box. Now, what I want to know is,how to reset all the three select box on clicking the remove button.

sample code is as under :-

```
<button ng-click="removeObj(key,model1,0)">Remove</span></button>
```

controller code is as under :-

```
scope.removeObj = function(modelID, subModelID, selectBoxPos) {
   modelID = 0;
   subModelID = 0;
})
```

I want on click of removeObj function all modelID data get reset to zero.

Please help.

Comment: what is `modelID` and `subModelID`. where it is declared

Comment: it will be more clear if you show your select boxes code

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you do not need any parameters.. only create a meaningful name `resetModels`:

AngularJS Controller:

```
$scope.resetModels = function() {
   // Set default value to your models...
   $scope.modelID = 0; 
   $scope.subModelID = 0;
});
```

Html:

```
<button ng-click="resetScpeModels()">Remove</span></button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I want when I am remove my first item it will reset all form. In other words it will reset all the select box on one click.

modelID and subModelID is parameter which have some value for current record only not for others

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset all the values. You should use it like this

```
     $scope.model = {};
     $scope.model.modelID = 0;
     $scope.model.subModelID = 0;

     <input ng-model="model.modelID"/>
```

If you want to reset it. Call again

```
    $scope.model = {};
```

Inside ng-click function.

Comment: I want to on single click all form data get reset by angular. I tried lots of things like JavaScript/Jquery, <input type=reset/> and all

Comment: This will fix your problem. Please create fiddle for it or show some live example.

Answer (score 0):

When you give a name to your `form` it automatically gets added to the `$scope`.

In angular we are having a `$setPristine()` method on the `$scope.formName`. which should recursively take care of resetting your form.

You can reset a form by, `$scope.formName.$setPristine();` but if you're binding a model object to your inputs, you need to take care of clearing those too, ie:

`$scope.formModel={};` or `angular.copy({}, formModel);`

**Working demo :**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.Reset = function(formModel) {
    angular.copy({}, formModel);
    $scope.formModel = {};
    $scope.submitForm.$setPristine();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <form name="submitForm" ng-controller="myController">
      <label for="first_field">First Model</label>
      <input ng-model="formModel.firstModel" />
      <br />
      <label for="second_field">Second Model</label>
      <input ng-model="formModel.secondModel" />
      <br />
      <button type="button" ng-click="Reset(formModel)">Reset</button>
    </form>
</div>
```